# Not able to categorize the rows

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

The loop is not working. I am trying to group the rows as per the if condition. However, after running the code, all the rows are being categorized into a single category 'global governance'

```
# create a for loop to re-group as per the values mentioned above

for values in data['Area']:
    if ((values=='corporate governance') | (values=='accounting') | (values== 'auditing') | (values=='manufacturing') | (values=='dao challenges')):
        data['final group']='corporate governance'
    
    elif (values=='blockchain governance' or values=='bct standards' or values== 'blockchain governance' or 
        values=='blockchain hashing' or values=='developers incentive' or values=='smart contract' or values=='Smart contract' ):
            data['final group']='Blockchain Technology Governance'   
        
    elif (values=='Block chain and legal compliance' or values=='Decision Rights' or values=='Dispute resolution' or
         values=='law' or  values=='judicature'):
            data['final group']='Judicature'
        
    elif (values == 'Blockchain and Trust'):
        data['final group']='Trust'
        
    elif ((values=='Foreign Aid') | (values=='Global Commons governance') | (values=='global Commons governance')):
        data['final group']='global governance'
        
    elif (values=='Public governance' or values=='Rural governance' or values=='Usage of bct in governance' or values=='public governance' or 
        values=='Smart city' or values=='smart city' or values=='Rural governance' or values=='national records'):
            data['final group']='governance'
        
    elif (values=='Music' or values=='Waste management' or values=='blockchian and healthcare' or values== 'forest management' or
        values=='healthcare' or 
        values=='Resource governance'):
                data['final group']='Resource governance'
    
    elif (values=='scientific publication' or values=='Academic Governance'):
        data['final group']='Academia'
        
    elif(values=='SDG' or values== 'carbon trading' or values=='environmental governance'):
        data['final group']='Sustainable developemnt'
        
    elif(values=='data governance' or values=='organisational data governance'):
        data['final group']='Data governance'
    
    elif(values=='digital platform governance' or values =='e commerce' or
       values=='platform governance' or values=='product management'):
            data['final group']='platform governance'
    
    elif(values=='Supplychain'):
        data['final group']=='Supplychain'
```

Comment: Use `df.head(10).to_clipboard(excel=False)` to copy the first 10 rows of your dataframe to clipboard (as text) which you can then paste into your question. Read this post on [how to provide a **good pandas example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but for readability a syntax change to `if values in ['corporate governance','accounting','auditing','manufacturing','dao challenges']:` would be much better. As for your issue, even though you are looping through your DF column, you are setting an entire column to a single value in each iteration. Likely the last `Area` in your dataframe aligns to `global governance`. Consider using something like `Apply` instead of looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding from my comment. Your loop loops through every row in column `Area` of your df; however, when it sets the value for column `final group` it's setting it for every row of the column. So the `Area` for your last row in your dataframe is determining the value of `final group` for every row. Instead consider something like `.apply()`:

```
def determine_final_group(area):
   
    if area in ['corporate governance','accounting','auditing','manufacturing','dao challenges']:
        return 'corporate governance'    
    elif area in ['blockchain governance','bct standards' ,'blockchain governance','blockchain hashing' ,'developers incentive' ,'smart contract' ,'Smart contract']:
        return 'Blockchain Technology Governance'           
    elif area in ['Block chain and legal compliance' ,'Decision Rights' ,'Dispute resolution', 'law','judicature']:
        return 'Judicature'        
    elif area == 'Blockchain and Trust':
        return 'Trust'        
    elif ['Foreign Aid','Global Commons governance','global Commons governance']:
        return 'global governance'
    
    #continue the elif logic using this pattern...  
   
data['final group'] = data['Area'].apply(determine_final_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do an assignment like `data['final group']='corporate governance'` it **assigns that value for the entire column**, not just the one row.

1. Put that into a function,
2. with a return for the final group (not assignment)
3. and remove the for-loop
4. use .map instead.

```py
def get_final_group(values):
    if values == 'corporate governance' or values == 'accounting' or values == 'auditing' or values == 'manufacturing' or values == 'dao challenges':
        return 'corporate governance'
    
    if (values == 'blockchain governance' or values == 'bct standards' or values == 'blockchain governance' or 
        values == 'blockchain hashing' or values == 'developers incentive' or values == 'smart contract' or values == 'Smart contract'):
        return 'Blockchain Technology Governance'  

    ...

df['final_group'] = df['Area'].map(get_final_group)
```

Notes and impprovements:

1. Since it's `returning` the value, you don't need `elif`.
2. Don't use `|` - that's for bit-wise OR.
3. Don't use excessive parenthesis, it's worse for readability
4. You can refactor the `if`'s to be more readable with something like:

   ```py
   if area in ('corporate governance',
               'accounting',
               'auditing',
               'manufacturing',
               'dao challenges'
           ):
       return 'corporate governance'

   # and so on
   ```
5. even better, use a dictionary to map the resulting values:

   ```py
   final_group = {
       'corporate governance': 'corporate governance',
       'accounting': 'corporate governance',
       'auditing': 'corporate governance',
       'manufacturing': 'corporate governance',
       'dao challenges': 'corporate governance',
       'blockchain governance': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'bct standards': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'blockchain governance': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'blockchain hashing': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'developers incentive': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'smart contract': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       'Smart contract': 'Blockchain Technology Governance',
       # and so on
   }
   df['final_group'] = df['Area'].map(final_group)
   ```
6. And since that gets really verbose, you can reverse it and use each target as the dictionary key, and the values would be all the possible ones for that, as a list or tuple:

   ```py
   final_group_categories = {
       'corporate governance': (
           'corporate governance',
           'accounting',
           'auditing',
           'manufacturing',
           'dao challenges',
       ),
       'Blockchain Technology Governance': (
           'blockchain governance',
           'bct standards',
           'blockchain governance',
           'blockchain hashing',
           'developers incentive',
           'smart contract',
           'Smart contract',
       ),
       # etc.
   }
   # then reverse it to use in the map function:
   final_group = {}
   for group_target, invals in final_group_categories.items():
       for inval in invals:
           final_group[inval] = group_target
   # same thing as a dict comprehension:
   final_group = {inval: group_target
                  for group_target, invals in final_group_categories.items()
                  for inval in invals
   }
   df['final_group'] = df['Area'].map(final_group)
   ```
7. Do the [matching on lowercase](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) so that you don't have duplicates like `'smart contract'` and `'Smart contract'`.

   ```py
   df['final_group'] = df['Area'].str.lower().map(final_group)
   ```